# Change Display Name in From field per Outlook instance

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm searching for a way to change the display name used for sending emails using Outlook. This is often used in CRM systems where multiple users use the same email address, but present themselves using their own name.

From a programming perspective, it's easily done:

- Original (As set in Exchange): `Info <info@company.com>`

  - Displayed by recipient as `Info`
- Changed: (As configured in 3rd party software) `Eddie Demon <info@company.com>`

  - Displayed by Recipient as `Eddie Demon`

Though the display names are different, the senders email address is the same. (`info@company.com`)

There are plenty of tips for IMAP/POP, but there isn't any for Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Because Exchange Server forces sender's name as it is in GAL. You can't really do anything here without writing custom transport agent for Exchange Server. And even this is not enough. You'll need the additional client solution (Outlook addin) that will place the desired From name to some header. After that, Exchange transport agent has to rewrite From based on the header's value.

Comment: Hi thims, can you name an add-in to alter the display name?

Comment: As I said, add-in is not enough. You need a complex solution addin+agent.

Comment: Oh well. That would take too much time. Thanks either way.